# How do I configure the Root Logger to be Async in Log4j via XML?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I want to have all async loggers, I know there's a way to globally set all loggers to be async, but I was thinking of just writing them as async in the XML file, However, I can't find any documentation on how to make the root logger async via XML. How can I configure the Root logger to be asynchronous using XML?

Comment: I believe the root logger has a blank name, so if you use `<AsyncLogger name=""...` that might work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mentioned in the comments `<AsyncLogger name="">` seems to work... but more correctly? we found `<AsyncRoot>`.

Comment: ... sure would be nice if there was an xsd